# Inconsistent Output in Google Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have the following basic code in Google Colab:

```
from random import *

number = randint(1, 100)

guess = int(input("Enter a guess: "))

while guess != number:
  if guess > number:
    print("Enter a smaller value")
  else:
    print("Enter a greater value")
  guess = int(input("Enter a guess: "))
  
print("You guessed the number")
```

This loop continues until we guess the number correctly. And after each guess, program directs us for the next guess (like enter smaller/greater number).

Sometimes, I get some inconsistency in the outputs. After I enter a wrong number as input, it should direct me with an output.

[image]

After I enter 40 as input, it does not show me the output as shown above. But after I enter the next input (42), it fixes the output screen and shows the missing output as below.

[image]

What might be the problem? It is happening all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Jupyter issue https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3159

My recommendation is to combine the prompt with the input request, e.g.,

```
from random import *

number = randint(1,100)
guess = int(input('Enter a guess: '))

while guess != number:
  if guess > number:
    prompt = 'Enter a smaller value\n'
  else:
    prompt = 'Enter a larger value\n'

  guess = int(input(prompt + 'Enter a guess: '))

print ('You guessed the number')
```

Here's a full example:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pCEn11NOCSbCGn91LIxY-Z5nCdVtc_sf

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it should be solved. I got in touch with colab team and they said that they will look into a fix [https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/226#issuecomment-409983396](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/226#issuecomment-409983396)